# How do i post data using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I tried to post the form data.but it didn't work.
Below is my code:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    // Controller function and passing $http service and $scope var.
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      // create a blank object to handle form data.
        $scope.user = {};
      // calling our submit function.
        $scope.submitForm = function() {
        // Posting data to  file
        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : '/tokken/d/',
          data    : $scope.user, //forms user object
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
          .success(function(data) {
            if (data.errors) {
              // Showing errors.
              $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
              $scope.erroPassword = data.errors.password;

            } else {
              $scope.message = data.message;
            }
          });
        };
    });
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Instead of using .success () , use .then()

Comment: please specify the exact problem. does _it didn't work_ mean the form data was not received on the other end or did an error occur ?

Comment: i got the answer. the error is due to some mistakes in my html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`$http.post()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  // Controller function and passing $http service and $scope var.
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    // create a blank object to handle form data.
    $scope.user = {};
    // calling our submit function.
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
      // Posting data to  file
      $http.post('/tokken/d/', $scope.user).then(function (data) {
        if (data.errors) {
          // Showing errors.
          $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
          $scope.erroPassword = data.errors.password;
        } else {
          $scope.message = data.message;
        }
      });
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.user is a JSON object not form-data
```

so you need to set content type as

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

you need to call the function on ng submit

In server you need to parse the json as data